# Find basis from coordinates?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to find the basis of coordinates, in respect to the vector that led to the coordinates?

If I had a point

\begin{align*} P = \begin{pmatrix}
px\\ 
py
\end{pmatrix} \end{align*}

and a vector

\begin{align*} V = \begin{pmatrix}
vx\\ 
vy
\end{pmatrix} \end{align*}

, then what is the Basis B={b1,b2}?

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write math expressions.

Comment: There wasn't really much to use Mathjax for, but here you go

Comment: There’s still more formatting to do. Be that as it may, what is the relationship between $V$ and $P$? What does $V$ have to do with this basis that you’re trying to find?